# Creating a 2d array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object -

```
cell{xPos, yPos};
```

I would like to create a 2d array of this object.

```
cellPrototype = function(x, y) {
this.xPos = x;
this.yPos = y;
}
var cell = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  cell[i] = new Array();
  for(var j=0;j<10;j++)
  {
     cell[i][j] = new cellPrototype(i,j);
  }
}
```

This code doesn't work.
Neither does -

```
var cellPrototype = function(x, y) {    
return { 
  xPos : x;
  yPos : y;
}
var cell = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  cell[i] = new Array();
  for(var j=0;j<10;j++)
  {
     cell[i][j] = new cellPrototype(i,j);
  }
}
```

So how do I create a 2d array of an object in javascript?

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood your question, your first example seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/tgz22/

Comment: What doesn't work? The second one at least give me an array with 10 arrays of 10 cellPrototypes each...

Comment: @James @josh.trow Don't know what happened. I have been testing this code on my computer for the last hour or two trying to make out what went wrong. After fiddling in jsFiddle for a bit I got it to work. Dunno, maybe some small typo somewhere was the problem. Everyone who answered & commented, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works fine for me, I'm not sure if that's exactly the output you're looking for, where 
`Array[x][y]` will reference an object with points at `x, y`.

```
var Coords = function(x, y) {
    return {
        "x" : x,
        "y" : y
    };
};

var Main = [];

for (var i = 0, l = 10; i < l; i++) {
    Main[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0, l2 = 10; j < l2; j++) {
        Main[i][j] = Coords(i, j);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/robert/d9Tgb/

Answer (score 2):

You can make a 2d array like so:

```
var new_array = [];
var arr_length = 10;
for(var i = 0; i < arr_length; ++i){
    new_array[i] = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit old, but here is another way to create a 2D array

```
var arr1=[];
var x=['a','b','c','d'];
var y=[1,2,3,4];     

for( var i in x){
    arr1.push([x[i],y[i]]); //For x and y of the same length
}
```

In JavaScript x and y can be objects arrays

[jsFiddle It :)](http://jsfiddle.net/daka90/wrK2H/)

Answer (score -1):

make an empty array and push the child arrays onto it

```
var array = [];
array.push([1,2,3,4]);
//array[0][0] == 1
```

or all in one shot

```
var array = [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]];
```

Comment: Those are not objects.