# Javascript two dimensional object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I'm trying to define arrays of objects, I can define one dimensional array of object but as I try to define the two dimensional I get a error. What is the correct way to define a multidimensional array of objects in Javascript? Here's my code :

```
for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
{
   obj1[i] = [
      {property1},{property2}
   ];
   for(var j=0;j<2;j++)
   {
      obj2[i][j]= [
         {property1},{property2}
      ];
   }
}
```

Comment: I searched google for your question and and it gave me 265,000 viable results in 1/3 of a second.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a 2d array of objects in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510864/creating-a-2d-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: First understand how to create 2d arrays in javascript using the link from @Johnny Henly and second learn how to use the object notation here http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/object-literal/. Your syntax is incorrect, you need to provide values for the properties you define

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
 f[i]=new Array();
 for (j=0;j<2;j++) {
  f[i][j] = appropriate property ;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, the answer is using it like this:

```
var obj1 = new Array();
var obj2 = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
{
   obj1[i] = [
      {property1},{property2}
   ];
   var obj2[i] = new Array();
   for(var j=0;j<2;j++)
   {
      obj2[i][j]= [
         {property1},{property2}
      ];
   }
}
```